# First order non linear differential equation solution with maximal interval of existence

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have some doubts about my way of resolving a Cauchy problem (with a differential equation as a separable equation). Here is the resolution, some questions at the bottom:

$$
y(t)y'(t)=1, y(0)=-2
$$

First of all I write it in the normal form:

$$
y'(t)= \frac{1}{y(t)}, y(0)=-2
$$

The differential equation is defined only for $y(t)\neq0$.

Now I separate the variables:
$$
\int_{} y dy=\int_{} dt
$$

Which results in: $y(t)=\pm\sqrt{2(t+c)}$

Now I impose the initial condition:
$$
-2 = -\sqrt{2(0+c)} \Rightarrow -\sqrt{2c} \Rightarrow c=2
$$

So the solution of the Cauchy problem is:

$$
y(t) = - \sqrt{2t+4}
$$

But the solution is not defined everywhere, $2t+4$ must be greater than or equal to $0$, so the solution is defined on the interval:

$$
t\geq -2
$$

But let's check the original differential equation, we told that it must be: $y(t)\neq0$ so the previous interval must be restricted to:

$$
t\gt -2
$$

Which is also the maximal interval of existence for the solution, which is:

$$
(y(t)=-\sqrt{2t+4}, (-2, +\infty))
$$

Now my questions:

1. Am I following the steps in the right way or am I messing with them?
2. Is it right to put the differential equation in the normal form before start the resolution? For me yes, because in this step I have found that $y(t)$ must be different than $0$, but I still have some doubts about it (my book is going too fast on this subject).

Comment: I don't know why someone would vote down this question. I think the question is very clear. My answers: 1. The solution is correct. 2. Putting it in normal form gives is a good way to see whether there exists a unique solution of this initial value problem. So yes.